# Expand short-hand css properties form js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am rewriting parts of style-sheets of a webpage of mine, dynamically on page load. (I have no better choice, believe me.) More specifically, I'm replacing `padding`, `margin`, and `border` properties with their `-webkit-*` equivalents, so for example `padding-left` becomes `-webkit-padding-start` and `padding-right` becomes `-webkit-padding-right`. (That is for better right-to-left support.)

I'm doing so by iterating through `document.styleSheets`, and visiting each rule and replacing the styles.

The problem is with the short-hand properties, like `padding` and `margin` and `border`. For `padding` and `margin`, I can split the text and other stuff, so I get the expanded properties (`padding-left`, `padding-right`, etc.). But `border` is very difficult to parse.

I was wondering if there is a good way to expand these properties more reliably. (Can I create some element dynamically, set the style to it, and get the expanded properties? Or something else?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I found out that `CSSStyleDeclaration` does that by itself. I was doing my operations in the wrong order.

Here is the result of my work, I hope someone finds it useful:

```
var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
for (var i = 0; i < styleSheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = styleSheets[i];
    if (!(sheet instanceof CSSStyleSheet)) {
        continue;
    }
    var rules = sheet.rules;
    for (var j = 0; j < rules.length; j++) {
        var rule = rules[j];
        if (!(rule instanceof CSSStyleRule)) {
            continue;
        }
        var style = rule.style;
        style.webkitPaddingStart = style.paddingLeft;
        style.webkitPaddingEnd = style.paddingRight;
        style.paddingLeft = "";
        style.paddingRight = "";
        style.webkitMarginStart = style.marginLeft;
        style.webkitMarginEnd = style.marginRight;
        style.marginLeft = "";
        style.marginRight = "";
        style.webkitBorderStartColor = style.borderLeftColor;
        style.webkitBorderEndColor = style.borderRightColor;
        style.webkitBorderStartStyle = style.borderLeftStyle;
        style.webkitBorderEndStyle = style.borderRightStyle;
        style.webkitBorderStartWidth = style.borderLeftWidth;
        style.webkitBorderEndWidth = style.borderRightWidth;
        style.borderLeftColor = "";
        style.borderRightColor = "";
        style.borderLeftStyle = "";
        style.borderRightStyle = "";
        style.borderLeftWidth = "";
        style.borderRightWidth = "";
    }
}
```